# Retrieve number of last page json request python

Tags: python, json, numpy, request

New in Python, I'd like to webscrape json data from
[https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?page[size]=200&page[number]=1&filter[entity.names]=*&filter[entity.legalAddress.country]=DE'](https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?page%5Bsize%5D=200&page%5Bnumber%5D=1&filter%5Bentity.names%5D=*&filter%5Bentity.legalAddress.country%5D=DE%27) without hard coding the number of page

Below is the code that I use and work

```
dfs = []


for i in np.arange(1, 20000):
    try:
        URL = f'https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?page[size]=200&page[number]={i}&filter[entity.names]=*&filter[entity.legalAddress.country]=DE'
        r = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies).json()

    v = pd.json_normalize(r['data'])
    dfs.append(v)
    print(f'Page {i}: Done')
    
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Page {i}: Error', e)
    break
```

Here is the Response

```
URL = f'https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records?page[size]=200&page[number]=1&filter[entity.names]=*&filter[entity.legalAddress.country]=DE'
r = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies).json() 
print(r)
```

Below is the output response

```
{'meta': {'goldenCopy': {'publishDate': '2020-09-17T00:00:00Z'}, 'pagination': {'currentPage': 1, 'perPage': 200, 'from': 1, 'to': 200, 'total': 139644, 'lastPage': 699}},
```

Question: How can I store 'lastPage' = 699 in a variable?
The goal would be to use the following loop

```
for i in np.arange(1, lastPage):
....
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lastPage = r.get('meta').get('pagination').get('lastPage')
```